# Get the id from a slug Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.1. So I want to create URL using this structure  : domain.tld/macbook-pro-2389 and using this route :

```
  Route::get('{sc}-{id}', 'ProductController@getDetails')
  ->where('id', '\d+');
```

But the problem I can't get exactly the Id when the slug contains multiple dashes.

How can i do that and keeping the same structure ?

**EDIT**

The only solution i did until now is to validate the whole slug with this regex `([a-z0-9\-]+)\-([0-9]+)` and then i explode the slug to get the last item like this :

```
 $id = explode('-', $slug);
 $id = end($id);

 Route::get('{slug}', function($slug){

 $id = explode('-', $slug);

 //  2389
 $idOnly = array_pop($id);

 // macbook-pro
 $nameDashes = implode('-', $id);

// It is possible to pass $idOnly and $nameDashes to `ProductController@getDetails` ?

 })
 ->where('slug', '([a-z0-9\-]+)\-([0-9]+)');
```

Comment: You cant, without creating regexp which will get You only numbers from `id` string, but it will be difficult if You have digits in your slugs

Comment: The only solution i did until now is to validate the whole slug with this regex `([a-z0-9\-]+)\-([0-9]+)` and then i explode the slug to get the last item like this : 
`$id = explode('-', $slug);`
`$id = end($id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by defining `sc` as well as `id`:

```
Route::get(
    '{sc}-{id}',
    function($sc, $id) {
        var_dump($sc);
        var_dump($id);
        exit;
    }
)
    ->where('sc', '.*?')
    ->where('id', '\d+');
```

In this scenario me [lazily match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) everything any amount of characters. Since it is lazy, it will go all the way until it sees the `-` followed by 1+ digits.

This ends up [parsing a regular expression similar to](http://regex101.com/r/kM5fA3):

```
^        (?# start of URL)
(.*?)    (?# capture sc)
-        (?# delimiter)
(\d+)    (?# capture id)
$        (?# end of URL)
```